# PHP, Efficient Way to Remove Html Formatting From a Tumblr API return

Tags: php, tumblr

So I'm fairly new to php. Only ever worked with js. But I'm currently experimenting with creating the post blurb to be shared on facebook/twitter, myself. More of an Exercise then anything else as the tumblr api returns an excerpt anyway. 
To put it simply I'm using tumblr as my "backend", what I post on tumblr, will appear on the website. bla bla bla.
I have php retrieving the tumblr data as json and is placed into a variable using json_decode.

Here is my current code to remove all the html and try and process it as a standard string, What I want to know is... is there a more efficient way of achieving the same result with php, so when the url is called on by facebook/twitter... my end will be able to present a description of the post.

```
    $json_TumblrDecoded = json_decode($tmblrjson, true);
    $reducedBodyText = str_replace(array('  '), ' ', str_replace(array('.'), '. ' , str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), ' ', strip_tags(html_entity_decode(substr($json_TumblrDecoded['response']['posts']['0']['body'],0,400))))));
```

Which will turn this;

```
<p>Keeping this post short.<br/>Good Movie, not Great Movie.<br/>It felt like there was a lot cut out (Apparently 40mins worth was).<br/>I think this is a really positive direction for movies based on video games to be headed.<br/>I can’t wait for a directors cut. <br/><br/>7/10 - Go and see it! <br/>It may not be the movie we deserved, but perhaps this is the movie we needed, if not just to get the franchise off the ground. I really think a sequel will prove what is capable.</p>
```

Into This;

```
"Keeping this post short. Good Movie, not Great Movie. It felt like there was a lot cut out (Apparently 40mins worth was). I think this is a really positive direction for movies based on video games to be headed. I can’t wait for a directors cut.  7/10 - Go and see it! It may not be the movie we deserved, but perhaps this is the movie we needed, if not just to ge"
```

Again. Is there a more Efficient Way to Achieving the end result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried PHP's `strip_tags` function?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Example below is from the link above:

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

Will output:

```
Test paragraph. Other text
```

Comment: Yep, this should work pretty well, if you just want to strip all tags

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a try!